# How to get item from list

Tags: ansible

Given this list:

```
colors:
  red: enabled
  yellow: enabled
  green: disabled
  blue: enabled
  purple: disabled
```

How can I get a list of the colors that are enabled (below doesn't work):

```
- debug:
     msg: "{{ item[0] }}"
  when: item[1] == 'enabled
  with_items: '{{ colors}}'
```

Guess I'm overthinking this as it seems like it should be quite simple.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example,

```yaml
colors_enabled: "{{ colors|dict2items|
                           selectattr('value', 'eq', 'enabled')|
                           map(attribute='key')|
                           list }}"
```

gives the list of enabled colors

```yaml
colors_enabled:
  - red
  - yellow
  - blue
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, this worked well. You are always so helpful.